# Trying to create a simple file server in PHP that shows descriptions for each file.

Tags: php, file, video-streaming

I am trying to create a simple video file server. I finished the skeleton of it but when it came to creating the multitude of pages I realized that there could be an easier way to do it.

I started out basically getting the folder names in the server then printing them on the page.

```
<?php
    $dirs = glob("*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($dirs as $dir)
    {
        $forbidden_folders = array("not4u", "ignore", Styles);
        $filename = str_replace($forbidden_folders, '', $dir);
        if (!empty($filename))
        {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$dir.'">'.$dir.'</a></li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>'
 ?>
```

Then I created in each of the folders with files a php file with this code:

```
<?php

function date_sort_desc($a, $b)
{
  preg_match('/\w+ \d{4}/', $a, $matches_a);
  preg_match('/\w+ \d{4}/', $b, $matches_b);
  $timestamp_a = strtotime($matches_a[0]);
  $timestamp_b = strtotime($matches_b[0]);
  if ($timestamp_a == $timestamp_b) return 0;
  return $timestamp_a < $timestamp_b;
}

$files = array();
$dir = opendir('.');
while(false != ($file = readdir($dir))) {
        if(($file != ".") and ($file != "..") and ($file != "index.php")) {
                $files[] = $file;
        }   
}

natsort($files);

$i = 0;
foreach($files as $file) {
$i++;
$string = str_replace("TV Show Name S1 E$i - ", '' , $file);
        echo '<div><a href="../Discriptions/'.$file.'.php">'.basename($string, '.m4v').'</a></div><br>';
}
?>
```

This opens up a php file with the same file name as the file to be played containing the episode's thumbnail and description. That file then contains a link pointing back to the real file. The problem here is that I'd have to make a new php file for every file in my collection. I'm wondering if there's somehow a way to simplify all of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a great opportunity to use a database table, though it will increase the complexity of your project and requires some knowledge of databases.  mysql would be perfect.

1. Create a table which stores the entire folder/file structure.
2. Populate the it with your first bit of code.  You will need to improve it so that adds new files/removes missing files from the table.  I might be best to mark items in the table as missing instead of deleting them so you don't lose your descriptions.   This code will also only be called by you manually whenever you make changes to what files are in the folders so put it in a separate php file from the file that users use to view the file listing.
3. Edit the table in the database manually with your favorite db tool to enter file descriptions.  Or you could write another php page to allow you to manage it from a browser with html forms, but that is a lot more work.
4. Instead of reading the filesystem on each page load, load your table from mysql and display it.  It contains your file names, descriptions, titles, etc already and will be much faster than reading the filesystem.  If you want, you could still call `file_exists` on each file to ensure it exists before you display a link to it in case your database table is outdated, but this will also slow down your page load.  You can also not show files marked as "missing"

You might also consider using a CMS which might require more setup time, but will take care of a lot of this back end work for you and provide an easy way to store descriptions and other things so you can focus on making your page look nice instead of basic tasks like parsing directories and files.

A CMS or mysql might be a bit daunting due to the additional learning curve and setup if you are not familiar with them alrady, so you could also consider just creating a text file to act in place of a database.  If you parse your files into a multidimensional array or array of objects, instead of outputting them to HTML immediately, you can easily serialize and de-serialize arrays and objects with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and store/retrieve those from a text file.  You could do that per directory or one for the entire site.  Once you have parsed all your files into a text file, you can edit that text file and add the descriptions so when you load it again each file has a description too.  Google `JSON Formatter` to find tools that will make the json more readable so you each quickly insert your descriptions.

You could also use XML, CSV, or your own propriety format if JSON isn't to your liking.

**Update** 
Take a look at the [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) class and search for examples of how to save/load.  I find XML to be a bit complicated to parse, but maybe SimpleXML will help. Take tiny steps so you don't get overwhelmed with the changes.  I would suggest a structure like

```
<files>
    <file>
      <absolutepath>/my/path/file1</absolutepath>
      <title>my file 1</title>
      <description>enter a description</description>
    </file>
    <file>
      <absolutepath>/my/path/file2</absolutepath>
      <title>my file 2</title>
      <description>enter a description</description>
    </file>
    ...
</files>
```

1. Build a SimpleXML object along side your code that is echoing the HTML.
2. After your HTML echo output loop, iterate your SimpleXML object that you constructed and use the data you stored into it to output all the information again so you can be sure it is what you want and you understand how it is being stored.
3. Once happy with how the XML object is storing your data, store the XML to a file.  I think you have to use asXML and write to a text file just like you would any other text to a file.
4. Open the text file and make sure your text file has the structure you expect. once it does, edit the text file and enter your descriptions.
5. Load the file back into XML with [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) and then iterate it for your output just like you did in step 2.
6. The real fun comes when you want to merge file changes with your file.  You can either edit it manually, or write instead of just reading the directory and generating a new file, you read the file into an XML object and then add/remove entries to match your filesystem.

This is turning into more of a tutorial than a specific answer, so I suggest you search around for tutorials on using saving/loading XML.  However, if you have time, this is a perfect project to learn how to use databases and there is plenty of info and examples available on how to setup, connect to, and manipulate simple mysql tables which would be much faster (code execution time) and, in the long term in my opinion, easier to work with and manipulate than XML files.

If you don't want to or don't have time to learn all that stuff, I suggest you go the static HTML route.  Use your PHP script to generate HTML as you are doing, then save that HTML to a separate static .html file for each directory (or combine into one) and add/edit/remove your file entries manually after the HTML is generated the first time.  If you are going to be editing the file descriptions manually anyway, this will be the quickest solution since the overhead of adding a link to the a file to your static HTML will probably only double the time it takes you to write each description.

Comment: I have no idea where to start to make any of this work. XML would be ideal for me considering that I want to make the server files as portable as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.htaccess` file in your root folder, and add the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
#Condition that it is NOT a directory trying to be accessed
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#Condition that the file does NOT exist, probably the .php file that was requested via the href
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#Send the request to the filePage.php file at your root
RewriteRule (.*) filePage.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,B]
```

Then also in the root folder, you'll have a `filePage.php` file that can handle the request.  The full URL that was requested will be passed into the `$_GET['q']` parameter.  You'll have to parse that parameter to be able to identify exactly which file was requested, something like this:

```
<?php
    $path = explode('/', $_GET['q']);
    if($path){
        $fileName = array_pop($path); //get the filename itself
        $folder = implode('/', $path); //reassemble the folder into a string

        if(file_exists($folder)) { //Does the folder exist?
            $file = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_FILENAME); //We don't care about the extension, because the request was for someFile.php
            $dirContents = scandir($folder);
            if($dirContents) { //Is there anything in the directory?  Probably yes.
                $realFileName = false;
                foreach($dirContents as $checkFile) {
                    if($file == pathinfo($checkFile, PATHINFO_FILENAME)) { //Found the actual file
                        $realFileName = $checkFile;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if($realFileName) {
                    //Here is where the magic happens.
                    //The request was made for nonexistent .php file with a legitimate real file counterpart.
                    //You may draw your information/landing page for the given file here.
                    //Use $folder.'/'.$realFileName as the url to the actual file.
                }
                else //404 here
            }
            else //404 here.  Probably will never happen.
        }
        else //404 here
    }
    else //404 here
```

Your server will need `mod_rewrite` on, and `AllowOverride = All` set in the sites-available.

This was a little verbose, but I wanted to make sure all the steps were easily readable.

Should be noted that this was written without the aid of a test environment, so it may contain errors.